# Possible to clone ViewVC SVN repositories?

Tags: linux, svn

Is it possible to clone or check out this svn repo which is hosted with ViewVC?

http://svnweb.mageia.org/adm/puppet/

Or is it http view only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewVC is simply a web interface to the repository and does not provide checkout facilities.

However, for that particular resource, it appears Mageia does provide anonymous access to their SVN repository (see [this wiki page](https://wiki.mageia.org/mw-en/index.php?title=Svn_for_translators&oldid=10061#Commands_for_everyone)). I was able to check out that repository path using:

```
svn co svn://svn.mageia.org/svn/adm/puppet
```

*P.S. You will need to use an svn client that supports the "svn" network protocol.*